# merge in hg / mercurial / kdiff3 shows conflicts where no exist

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging, kdiff3

I've got nice mercurial repository with several branches. 
When I merge the changes from one branch to another (eg test to stable) mercurial sometimes gives me lots of conflict Messages like this one:

```
---------------------------
Conflicts
---------------------------
Total number of conflicts: 10
Nr of automatically solved conflicts: 10
Nr of unsolved conflicts: 0
Files A and B are binary equal.
---------------------------
&OK   
---------------------------
```

Funny Thing is: There are no conflicts - why does hg / kdiff3 Show conflicts when the binary files are equal??

Comment: The conflict may be a function of activity in the history rather than actual binary differences. If you look at the common ancestors of the merged changesets and see if the files that you're interested were edited in either of the branches, they could maybe have been edited in the same way in both branches even if the end result was the same thing. Revset queries for this would be `descendants(common_parent) and file("filepath")` or `descendants(common_parent) and ancestors(merge_changeset) and file("filepath")`

Comment: I had a similar scenario when merging a huge chunk of history, and had ended up with the same file, but it had arrived at the same location by different means on each branch although they were binary equal.